# How to Save Multiple Objects At Once in Django

Tags: django, ajax

I created a checkbox in each row of the table. After selecting multiple check boxes, click the Add Teacher button to add the currently logged in user name (request.user.first_name) to the 'teacher' field of the checked row. I succeeded in getting the id to the page with the table using ajax, but it keeps failing to add the field value of obejct(teacher field) at once. view.py needs to be edited, does anyone know how to fix it?

[urls.py]

```
path('/study/add_teacher/', views.add_teacher, name='add_teacher'),
path('/study/student/', views.student),  ----> page with table
```

[views.py]

```
def add_teacher(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ids = request.POST.getlist('chkArray')

        for id in ids:
            student = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
            student.teacher = request.user.first_name
            student.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/study/student/') ----> page with table
```

[stduent.js]

```
$(function () {
    ('button.addteacher').on('click',function () {
        $checkbox = $('.Checked');

        var chkArray = [];
        var updateTeacher = confirm("업데이트하시겠습니까?");
        chkArray = $.map($checkbox, function(el){
            if(el.checked) { return el.id };
        });

        var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();

        $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: '/study/add_teacher/',
                headers: {"X-CSRFTOKEN": "{{ csrf_token }}"},
                data:{
                    "chkArray" : chkArray.toString(),
                    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(chkArray);
                },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
       });

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you plsease share your `Student` model?

Comment: `"chkArray" : chkArray.toString(),` does not seem to make much sense, since then you convert the list to a string. Likely it is better to make a JSON request.

Comment: class Studnet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], null=True)
    register_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)